# Decrease linespacing in margin notes of the fixme package?

Tags: line-spacing, marginpar, fixme

Is it possible to get single-spaced marginnotes in a double-spaced document?

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[draft]{fixme}
\linespread{2}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\fxnote{this is a multi-line margin note note note note }
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are several ways to get margin notes. You mention the `fixme` package in the question title. Perhaps you could add a little example to show how you are getting your margin notes, and what method you are using to double space your document.

Comment: I updated the question with a minimal example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the `marginface` setup:

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[draft]{fixme}
\linespread{2}

\fxsetup{marginface=\linespread{1}\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\fxnote{this is a multi-line margin note note note note }
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Note that using the `setspace` package is better than using `\linespread` in the wild.